# Pandas how to resample between specific dates and sum values within date ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

(This questions is a follow up of [How to use pandas Grouper with 7d frequency and fill missing days with 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323065/how-to-use-pandas-grouper-with-7d-frequency-and-fill-missing-days-with-0))

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'names': ['joe', 'joe', 'joe'],
    'dates': [dt.datetime(2019,6,1), dt.datetime(2019,6,5), dt.datetime(2019,7,1)],
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2019,5,1),
    'end_date': dt.datetime(2019,7,5),
    'values': [5,2,13]
})

  names      dates start_date   end_date  values
0   joe 2019-06-01 2019-05-01 2019-07-05       5
1   joe 2019-06-05 2019-05-01 2019-07-05       2
2   joe 2019-07-01 2019-05-01 2019-07-05      13
```

and I want to resample the data in 7 days blocks, with date ranges defined by `start_date` and `end_date`.

I was able to achieve the result I'm looking for by using the following workaround

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dates': [df.start_date.tolist()[0], dt.end_date.tolist()[0]],
    'names': df.names.tolist()[0],
    'values': 0
})

concat_df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], axis=0, sort=True)

concat_df.set_index('dates').groupby('names').resample('7D').sum()
```

which outputs

```
                  values
names dates             
joe   2019-05-01       0
      2019-05-08       0
      2019-05-15       0
      2019-05-22       0
      2019-05-29       5
      2019-06-05       2
      2019-06-12       0
      2019-06-19       0
      2019-06-26      13
      2019-07-03       0
```

which is what I'm looking for.

I'm pretty sure there are better ways to achieve that. Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to reindex you current time series, avoiding the `pd.concat` can yield better results.

```
df.set_index('dates', inplace=True)
def groupbyResample(groupby):
    date_range = pd.date_range(groupby.start_date.min(), groupby.end_date.max(), 
                               freq='d', name='date_index')

    return date_range.to_frame(name='dates').join(groupby).resample('7D')['values'].sum()

df.groupby('names').apply(groupbyResample).stack()
```

Result:

```
names  date_index
joe    2019-05-01     0.0
       2019-05-08     0.0
       2019-05-15     0.0
       2019-05-22     0.0
       2019-05-29     5.0
       2019-06-05     2.0
       2019-06-12     0.0
       2019-06-19     0.0
       2019-06-26    13.0
       2019-07-03     0.0
dtype: float64
```

Using magic function `%%timeit`:

```
%%timeit
def groupbyResample(groupby):
..
7.9 ms ± 352 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Your Approach:

```
%%timeit
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({ ..
9.1 ms ± 394 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

There isn't much performance-enhancement, however, using a function does scale well and you won't have write a lot of code yourself. That being said, I still feel that there is a more *idiomatic* way to do it.